# Change hardcoded values in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, hardcode

I would like to change hardcoded values in my code. I would like the code to replace and change hardcoded values based on the number of times it runs. Beginning with:

```
x=1
```

The next time, after I run it, in the code itself, I would like to see in the code editor:

```
x=2
```

It will automatically change the values of the code without human input, so the third time its run:

```
x=3
```

And this is all done just by the script running, no human interaction whatsoever. Is there an easy way?

Comment: One option would be to open in write mode your .py file at the end of your script, find the line you want to modify and replace the value.

Comment: Possible, of course - most things are. Desirable? Not really. If this value needs to persist across runs, then look at storing it in a file which you can load from your script each time.

Comment: Sure they are possible, but is there an easy way? I would like the values to be dynamic , like that 1 become 2. Let me rephrase it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write to a well-defined auxiliary file:

```
# define storage file path based on script path (__file__)
import os
counter_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'my_counter')
# start of script - read or initialise counter
try:
    with open(counter_path, 'r') as count_in:
        counter = int(count_in.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    counter = 0

print('counter =', counter)

# end of script - write new counter
with open(counter_path, 'w') as count_out:
        count_out.write(str(counter + 1))
```

This will store an auxiliary file next to your script, which contains the `counter` verbatim.

```
 $ python3 test.py
 counter = 0
 $ python3 test.py
 counter = 1
 $ python3 test.py
 counter = 2
 $ cat my_counter
 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use config parser to store run counter in a file

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config_fn = 'program.ini'

try:
    config.read(config_fn)
    run_counter = int(config.get('Main', 'run_counter'))
except configparser.NoSectionError:
    run_counter = 0
    config.add_section('Main')
    config.set('Main', 'run_counter', str(run_counter))
    with open(config_fn, 'w') as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)

run_counter += 1
print("Run counter {}".format(run_counter))
config.set('Main', 'run_counter', str(run_counter))
with open(config_fn, 'w') as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)
```